# Facebook Graph API - country name from country code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have following problem with Facebook Graph API. My use case is that I want to retrieve complete country object (like returned by [Autocomplete-data for countries](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data#) ) based on the country code. I've noticed that they claim that there is **"match_country_code"** bool that if one will set it to **"1 or true"** then **"q"** param can contain country code, and that this should return the country object.

Unfortunately it doesn't. Does anyone have any idea why? My example query looks like:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=['country']&q=GB&match_country_code=1
```

I've tried with **true** instead of **1**, but still... no effect.

Thanks in advance for any help or hint.

Comment: I've seen this issue too and didn't find an answer...

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=[%27city%27]&limit=10000&q=GB
Try this facbook list of countries & cities.